# org-publish-project fails because of defective org-links - repair links automatically or ignore them?

Tags: org-mode, org-link, org-publish

I'm trying to "quickly" export my notes ans tasks from org-mode to a html-page with org-publish-projects.

I had a working setup some years ago and I'm trying to reactivate it, but doing the export constantly throws errors like "Unable to resolve link "name of heading" (also some links to entries with custom IDs gave errors).

If I repair each link manually, I loose to much time.

- Can I make org-publish ignore skip those defective links and just list them in the log messages?
- is there a way to repair those links automatically?

Comment: I guess these are internal links?  Maybe these could be fixed with some advanced use of query-replace-regexp?  What's wrong with these links, exactly?

Comment: I don't know in detail. It is some internal links and some with a custom ID and also some links to files - I would have to go through them one by one and I do not have the time for that. so for the moment I would prefer org-publish ignoring those links and just publish what's there instead of publishing _nothing at all_ :-(

Comment: @JeanPierre: I had a very large file with notes and I've restructured it, splitted the notes to different org-files, grouped them below different headings etc. So the internal links seem to be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can set the variable `org-export-with-broken-links`:

> org-export-with-broken-links is a variable defined in ‘ox.el’.
>   Its value is t
>   Original value was nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means do not raise an error on broken links.
>
> When this variable is non-nil, broken links are ignored, without
>   stopping the export process.  If it is set to ‘mark’, broken
>   links are marked as such in the output, with a string like
>
> [BROKEN LINK: path]
>
> where PATH is the un-resolvable reference.
>
> This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword, e.g.,
>   "broken-links:mark".